# undefined variable while i defined it

Tags: php, laravel, image, variables

so im trying to make sure that if i upload an  imagefile (a profile update for my user) that i'm fetching the filepath but i get an Undefined variable:imagePath error.

so i tried to dd my imagepath but it came out with noting while i do define it.

i want to put the filepath here

```
$data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'url' => 'url',
            'image' => '', //filepath here
        ]);
```

here i define it.

```
if(request('image'))
        {
            $imagePath = request('image')->store('profile', 'public'); //here i define the variable

            $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1000, 1000); // here i try to use it
            $image->save();
        }

dd(array_merge(
            $data,
            ['image' => $imagePath] //the error occurs here while trying to merge
        ));
```

so i expected this array merge to give me a readable path but i get an error instead. i might've made a spelling mistake somewehre as english is not my first language but i read over my code and it all looks to be okay.

Comment: If your request does not have a key `'image'`, it is possible the `$imagePath` variable is never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `{}`

```php
$image = Image::make(public_path("storage/$imagePath"))->fit(1000, 1000);
```

or concatenate separately

```php
$image = Image::make(public_path('storage/'.$imagePath))->fit(1000, 1000);
```

Let's say `$imagePath = 'randomString'`, the code will try to get the variable named `randomString` if you use it like this `{$imagePath}`.

We use this trick to call dynamic variables.

```php
$textVariable = 'this text';
$text2 = 'textVariable';
echo ${$text2}; // will echo "this text"
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
if($request->image)
        {
            $imagePath = $request->image->store('profile', 'public'); //here i define the variable

            $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/".$imagePath))->fit(1000, 1000); // here i try to use it
            $image->save();
        }

dd(array_merge(
            $data,
            ['image' => $imagePath] //the error occurs here while trying to merge
        ));
```

I just change your `request('image')` to `$request->image` and remove the `{}` here `$image = Image::make(public_path("storage/".$imagePath))->fit(1000, 1000);`

I assume that you're in controller and you have `Request $request`

Hope it helps.

Comment: making the request a varibale doesnt work but thanks anway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    $sqlit_del_imgs = explode(",", "$delelte_product_images");
    foreach($split_del_prd_imgs as $img_name) {
        unlink("products_img/" . $_GET["prd_id"] ."/" . $img_name);
}
```